# Daterangepicker or alternative datepicker to disable booked out days in calendar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, daterangepicker

I would like to use Dan Grossman's [daterangepicker](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker) for a reservation system, where user chooses time intervals on booking. 
I still search in documentation if is possible to disable booked out dates from calender but I do not really find any of detail.

On show calendar I gather all bookings for the actual property, which return 2 dates the `check in` and `check out` times. Now how do I disable the days between in the selectable calendar?

The ajax request looks like this:

```js
$('#reservation').on('show.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {

  // Ajax method to return all booked intervals for actual property
  // which returns from and to dates as JSON
  $.request('onAvailability', {
    data: {
      id: $("input[name=property_id]").val()
    }
  });

});
});
```

Is there a way to achieve this?  Or is there already a plugin which would be resonable for my needs?

Comment: minDate: (Date object, moment object or string) The earliest date a user may select    |   

maxDate: (Date object, moment object or string) The latest date a user may select

Comment: @Yvenne Info asking the Author of the Plugin,  got the answer that is not capable to achive what I want, but if you have a suitable workaround I would appreciate that if you would share

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Possible solution ( http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker, beforeShowDay calback ):

[image: sample implementation]

it hows that you can show selected days, begin and end ( darker green ), unavailable days ( image X ), and incorrect selection ( transparent image X witch background )

If you still want to use Dan Grossman's daterangepicker, I can write modification which will allow handle unavailable days.

Comment: thank you for feedback. Yes already switched to this plugin but I have some difficulty with `beforeShowDay`  callback can you show me how did you solved ?

Comment: I'm also interested in a solution like this. DId any of you guys get it to work properly?